# Using \input for the gantt options

Tags: input, pgfgantt

I am having an issue with using \input to enter the gantt chart options.

The command for a gantt chart is:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[options]{start tss}{end tss}
· · ·
\end{ganttchart}
```

In place of [options] I am trying to input a file that has my standard Gantt chart options so that I only have to change these options in one place for the two version of my Gantt (two different audiences getting different milestones).

So, my compile file has this code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\newcommand{\sdate}{2020-01-01}
\newcommand{\edate}{2020-08-31}
\newcommand{\ct}{blue}  % Color Theme
\newcommand{\tc}{\Large\bfseries\color{white}} % Title Text Format
\newcommand{\dn}[1]{*#1{draw=none}} % Shorthand for draw=none
\newcommand{\ws}{dashed}  % Style for weekly vertical lines
\newcommand{\ms}{line width=1pt}    % Style for Monthly vertical lines
\newcommand{\td}{2020-01-10}
\newcommand{\gnl}{\ganttnewline[thick, red]}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}  
    \input{timeline.tex}
    \ganttbar{\tiny{Model Development}}{2020-01-01}{2020-03-15}\\
    \ganttbar{\tiny{Model Verification}}{2020-02-20}{2020-03-31}\\
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

timeline.tex looks like:

```
% Gantt Settings
[
    canvas/.append style={very thick},
    expand chart=\textwidth,
    time slot format=isodate,
    today/.expanded = \td,
    today offset=.5,
    today rule/.style={draw=\ct, thick},
    today label font = \tiny,
    today label node /.append style = {anchor = north west},
    today label = Today,
    title/.append style={fill=\ct!50},
    y unit title=0.5cm,
    title height=0.8,
    title label font = \tc,
    bar/.append style={fill=\ct!10},
    bar height = 0.3,
    inline,
    milestone inline label node/.append style={left=5mm},
    milestone height = 0.5,
    milestone/.append style={xscale = 5, fill=\ct}
]
{\sdate}{\edate}

\gantttitle{Project Timeline}{244} \\ % title 1
\gantttitlecalendar*{\sdate}{\edate}{month=shortname} \\
```

All the options worked when everything was in one file, so I doubt the problem is with the contents of timeline.tex.  The error I get is something like "missing numbers".  I tried putting the braces in the compile document and only the options in \input and that didn't work either.

Can anyone shed some light on this?  I thought \input just literally copied and pasted the contents from the other file....

Those last two code blocks should be a MWE (or not working example).

Comment: I do not think this will work like that. However, I also do not understand why you are doing this precisely this way. You could just make the contents of the file become a style definition, i.e. the stuff enclosed by`[...]` becomes `\ganttset{mystyle/.style={...}}`. Then you can input the file and use `\begin{ganttchart}[mystyle]{\sdate}{\edate}`.

Comment: I just tried that and now I get an error about an undefined control sequence on the \begin{ganttchart} line.  I know the package is loaded....is there something else I have to load?

Comment: It is hard to debug this since I do not see precisely what you are doing. I had tested what I proposed above, and in my case it worked.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  Maybe I will read up on the styles and see if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

`\input` does not work in the way you want to use it. There is the `catchfile` package which in principle allows you to store the contents of a file in a macro, and conceivably this will work here. However, I'd suggest to go another route. This is a version that works in principle. Change your file `timeline.tex` to become

```
\ganttset{mygantt/.style={canvas/.append style={very thick},
    expand chart=\textwidth,
    time slot format=isodate,
    today/.expanded = \td,
    today offset=.5,
    today rule/.style={draw=\ct, thick},
    today label font = \tiny,
    today label node /.append style = {anchor = north west},
    today label = Today,
    title/.append style={fill=\ct!50},
    y unit title=0.5cm,
    title height=0.8,
    title label font = \tc,
    bar/.append style={fill=\ct!10},
    bar height = 0.3,
    inline,
    milestone inline label node/.append style={left=5mm},
    milestone height = 0.5,
    milestone/.append style={xscale = 5, fill=\ct}
}}
\pgfkeys{myganttcommands/.code={\gantttitle{Project Timeline}{244} \\ % title 1
\gantttitlecalendar*{\sdate}{\edate}{month=shortname} \\}}
```

and then use

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\newcommand{\sdate}{2020-01-01}
\newcommand{\edate}{2020-08-31}
\newcommand{\ct}{blue}  % Color Theme
\newcommand{\tc}{\Large\bfseries\color{white}} % Title Text Format
\newcommand{\dn}[1]{*#1{draw=none}} % Shorthand for draw=none
\newcommand{\ws}{dashed}  % Style for weekly vertical lines
\newcommand{\ms}{line width=1pt}    % Style for Monthly vertical lines
\newcommand{\td}{2020-04-15}%<-added
\begin{document}
\input{timeline.tex}
\begin{ganttchart}[mygantt]{\sdate}{\edate}  
    \pgfkeys{myganttcommands}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

I doubt that your code with precisely the specified data works, for instance I had to add `\newcommand{\td}{2020-04-15}` to make an error message go away. If you provide me with a version that yields a good output I will be happy to append the answer by something that reproduces this using the above method.

Comment: Ah, that did it.  Sorry about the missing "today" command.  That somehow got deleted in the copy/paste process!  I can add that back into the original question.  I guess I don't understand why \input doesn't work here though.  Can anyone recommend a tutorial on pgfkeys and styles?  I have looked at documentation but it confuses me a little sometimes.  Like how did you know to use .code to make the last two lines appear?

Comment: @Jennifer The pgf key management is explained in section **87 Key Management** of the pgf manual. All I am doing here is to pack the collections of keys in a style `mygantt`, which gets loaded and "unpacked" with `\input{timeline.tex}
\begin{ganttchart}[mygantt]...` As for the question why `\input` does not work in the way you want it to work: TeX expands the macros in certain ways, and it does not, when expanding the stuff contained in `\begin{ganttchart}` expand `\input{timeline.tex}`. This is the reason why there are dedicated packages like `catchfile`.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried to read Key Management, but it's a bit above my LaTeX knowledge.  Maybe once I finish this pesky dissertation I can work through that section slowly and type actual documents to try things out....